# What is the advantage of useDispatch over simply exporting dispatch from store config?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been working with react-redux using hooks, and I just don't get what is the advantage of using react-redux useDispatch over just the dispatch function from store object.

In the begging of react-redux, when I was using mapDispatch with connect I just get it, is good to avoid nesting redux into React components. But by now, using hooks, it's clear that the component is well aware of redux. So, why not just use the dispatch function?

Comment: If I understood you correctly - you want to import `store` object to every single component that has to dispatch actions?

Comment: Almost... In fact I want to export store.dispatch like this: `export const dispatch: AppDispatch = store.dispatch;` and import in every component that needs it.

Comment: You should probably avoid that - see more https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#store-setup-multiple-stores

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Like that FAQ suggests and Gaeron told in this issue: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1436#issuecomment-187646474, the biggest concern is having multiple stores. Which normally is a server side render practice. Maybe it is a matter of caring about a wider pattern and compatibility. Right?

Comment: Imo if your app doesnt have to be on some enterprise level and you probably wont implement SSR, you can use it as you mentioned above.

Comment: I would definitely respect that recommendation on my professional projects. By the way, I was just annoyed of having that dumb "const dispatch = useDispatch()" wasting space in the middle of my component logic (plus imports). I was thinking in use that singleton dispatch store on a personal project. However that discussion made me evaluate the benefits of breaking a pattern over 1 extra line.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys. It made me think about component isolation and reuse. It is worth having a method of isolation like useDispatch, as it allows you to extract components on multiple apps and don't even care about which store you're dispatching actions. That might be the holly grail of redux...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from making it easily available in your components, react hooks tend to be better for performance as they are smartly implemented and use techniques like memoization

Also importing store directly in you react components is considered an anti-pattern and is not recommended as your store will de facto become a singleton

Comment: I don't believe this case is a matter of perfomance. It looks indeed a bad practice as your app might grow and you should care to isolate components without worrying which part of your app provides the store...